# Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-vfs://github+

Tags: c, git, visual-studio-code, github, version-control

I am unable to upload and replace a folder with C files in github.dev (Web IDE in GitHub which opens VS code in your browser). If I go to max depth of each folder, I am able to upload and replace all the files the folder contains - not scalable since in a real world scenario you'd need to visit each folder separately.

So when I try to upload the folder, I am asked if I want to replace, I choose yes and then I get:

> Unable to resolve nonexistent file
> 'vscode-vfs://github+7b2276223a312c22726566223a7b2274797065223a352c226964223a226d61696e227d7d/gsamaras/test_for_web_vs_code/alpha'

Steps to reproduce (in a test public repo I created):

1. Go to [gsamaras/test_for_web_vs_code](https://github.com/gsamaras/test_for_web_vs_code/tree/main) GitHub repo.
2. Click on green button "Code" -> Download ZIP.
3. On your PC, unzip the downloaded ZIP.
4. Back in GitHub, click on README.md.
5. Click the downwards arrow right of edit button (pencil icon) -> Open
   with github.dev.
6. Once the web IDE appears in your browser, drag & drop the contents
   of test_for_web_vs_code folder from your PC to the web IDE.
7. Choose "Yes" for replace -> See the error.

---

Screenshot of error:
[image]

After the error, the folder is gone (neither the new folder gets uploaded, nor the old one stays there):
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug in github.dev. There's probably some way to report bugs in it.

Comment: @Kodiologist there is no issues tab on their repo for bug reporting: https://github.com/github/dev